# Tridion: Errors when setting a page's metadata schema in the event system

Tags: .net, events, tridion

This is on Tridion 2011 SP1.

I'm using the component save event in the Tridion event system to create a corresponding page and associate some metadata with that page. When specifying a schema, I am getting event logs that indicate that the UUID of the schema cannot be found.

The UUID that is in the error is the for the metadata schema I want to use, and I'm also using a local TcmUri for the metadata schema. I'm at a bit of a loss at the moment.

The .NET and resulting error are below:

Code

```
public static TcmUri CreatePage(TcmUri parentSgId, Component component, TcmUri componentTemplateUri, TcmUri metaDataSchemaUri = null)
    {
        Logging.Debug("Attempting to create page in " + parentSgId.ToString());
        Page page = new Page(component.Session, parentSgId);
        page.Title = component.Title;
        page.FileName = component.Title;
        // Add a metadata schema
        if (metaDataSchemaUri != null)
        {
            TcmUri localMetaDataSchemaUri = TransformTcmUri(metaDataSchemaUri, parentSgId);
            page.MetadataSchema = (Schema)page.Session.GetObject(localMetaDataSchemaUri);
        }
        // Add the CP
        TcmUri localComponentUri = Helpers.TransformTcmUri(component.Id, parentSgId);
        TcmUri localComponentTemplateUri = Helpers.TransformTcmUri(componentTemplateUri, parentSgId);
        page.ComponentPresentations.Add(new ComponentPresentation(new Component(localComponentUri, component.Session), new ComponentTemplate(localComponentTemplateUri, component.Session)));
        try
        {
            page.Save(true);
            Logging.Debug("Created page successfully " + page.Id.ToString());
            return page.Id;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Error

```
Unable to find uuid:C42EE4FC-D2A2-49F5-92C7-BF6DCB014343:Metadata.
Component: Tridion.ContentManager Errorcode: 0 User: EMAKINA\MTSUser
StackTrace Information Details: at
Bair.Tridion.Events.Utilities.Helpers.CreatePage(TcmUri parentSgId,
Component component, TcmUri componentTemplateUri, TcmUri
metaDataSchemaUri) [...]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem, as pointed out by Quirijin was that I wasn't setting the metadata for the page before attempting to save it. The working code is below.

Setting the page metadata

```
if (metaDataSchemaUri != null)
            {
                Helpers.SetPageMetaData(metaDataSchemaUri, parentSgId, component, ref page);
            }
```

The SetPageMetaData method

```
 protected static void SetPageMetaData(TcmUri metaDataSchemaUri, TcmUri parentSgId, Component component, ref Page page)
        {
        TcmUri localMetaDataSchemaUri = TransformTcmUri(metaDataSchemaUri, parentSgId);
        page.MetadataSchema = (Schema)page.Session.GetObject(localMetaDataSchemaUri);
        ItemFields metaFields = new ItemFields((Schema)page.Session.GetObject(localMetaDataSchemaUri));
        Logging.Debug("Schema title: " + page.MetadataSchema.Title);
        // Set the page metadata

            TextField pageTitle = (TextField)metaFields["pagetitle"];
            pageTitle.Value = "The page title";
[...]
            KeywordField showbreadcrumb = (KeywordField)metaFields["showbreadcrumb"];
            showbreadcrumb.Value = new Keyword(TransformTcmUri(new TcmUri("tcm:134-12018-1024"), parentSgId), page.Session);
[...]
        }
        page.Metadata = metaFields.ToXml();
        Logging.Debug("Page metadata set");
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to replicate your error in my own image. After some investigation I was able to figure out what the issue. The error "Unable to find uuid:C42EE4FC-D2A2-49F5-92C7-BF6DCB014343:Metadata" means that setting the Schema is ok, but it can't find that element in the Page's XML. You have to explicitly set .Metadata as well! Here's what I did to successfully save a Page and add the metadata schema:

```
    private void SetMetadata(Page page, SaveEventArgs eventArgs, EventPhases phases)
    {
        try
        {
            Schema schema = (Schema)page.Session.GetObject("tcm:3-5806-8");

            if (page.MetadataSchema == null)
            {
                page.MetadataSchema = schema;
                ItemFields metadata = new ItemFields(schema);
                TextField showInNav = (TextField)metadata["showinmenu"];
                showInNav.Value = "No";
                page.Metadata = metadata.ToXml();
                SetPageMetadata.LogMessage("Set Page Metadata");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SetPageMetadata.LogMessage("An error occurred while rsetting the Page metadata:\n" + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this also, but with the same error result unfortunately.

Comment: Damn it, you figured it out before I managed to post my solution... :/

Comment: Sorry. Thanks very much for digging into this one. I banged my head against it for a while and the solution just popped out ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the schema for any issues?  Does it contain that namespace value (uuid:C42EE4FC-D2A2-49F5-92C7-BF6DCB014343:Metadata).  Sometimes it is worth clearing out your browser cache and restarting the CME to be sure you are looking at the latest schema.

Comment: The namespace value exists. I've tried creating a new page metadata schema and using this one instead but with the same error result (The UUID in the error is now the one of the new schema).